# How to create filters in Photoshop and export for iOS/Android?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, ios, filter

[image]

What is the design process for creating camera filters in Photoshop (like in Instagram for example), and then exporting them for use on a iOS/Android app?

I can use Curves to create an adjustment layer, and export the .acv for the developers to use on IOS. But I want to know if there is another way, or a more "correct" way to create the Instagram like filters.

There are so many apps using filters of different natures, so there must be a way for a designer to create and calibrate things and then give those values or .acv's to the developers.

Comment: This question appears to have more to do with programming than graphic design.

Comment: There is a infinite number of filters and each application implements different controls so its not really possible. But this is something you need to talk with YOUR developers with.

Comment: In photoshop you can make all of the instagram filters and millions more, so you have to choose a specific filter and we'll help you find out how to make it!

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit misinformed. Or possibly misspelled? Photoshop manipulates pixels, does not make programs for manipulating pixels.

You could, however, preview your filter in Photoshop. Photoshop does not have any way of exporting the filter tough, just the result of those filters. At the and of the day your much more likely to get forward if you just write a fronted to software like [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) instead.

Comment: Hello joojaa, thank your very much for your answer. I can use Curves to create an adjustment layer, and export the .acv for the developers to use on ios. But i wanted to know if there is another way, or a "correct" way to create the Instagram like filters. There are so many apps using filters of different natures, so there must be a way for a designer to create and calibrate things and then give those values or .acv's to the developers. I hope that i am making my self clear. Once again thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: @RicardoCoelho Your not actually making a filter your just taking the settings of a filter in Photoshop and saved them. then you have the same filter programmed in your app that replicates Photoshops functions. In essence your previewing the filter in Photoshop as i said. Aside for acf theere is not many other filters that have save capabilities, perhaps convolve. If your app has all the same filters as Photoshop than you could write the settings and application order down. Not very conductive approach imho.